# How to get CfnFunction from SingletonFunction with AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I want to get access to the underlying `CfnFunction` of a `SingletonFunction` within AWS CDK.  Normally, to access a L2 object such as `CfnFunction` from a L1 construct such as `SingletonFunction`, you would do this:

```
SomeL2Resource l2 = (SomeL2Resource)someL1Resource.getNode().getDefaultChild()
```

However, `SingletonFunction` attaches its underlying function to the stack, instead of itself, see [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/7568#issuecomment-629177022), with a link to the underlying code being [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/9f35104d2e6612032f2c6d8d7193baddceb30d15/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-lambda/lib/singleton-lambda.ts#L76).  I think this is the reason why if I call `getNode().getDefaultChild()` on an instance of `SingletonFunction` I get null returned.  How do I get the `CfnFunction`?

```
SingletonFunction singletonFn = SingletonFunction.Builder.create(...);
CfnFunction cfnFunction = (CfnFunction)singletonFn.getNode().getDefaultChild();
assert(cfnFunction != null); // fails, how do I get CfnFunction?
```

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with the research you [provided](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/9f35104d2e6612032f2c6d8d7193baddceb30d15/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-lambda/lib/singleton-lambda.ts#L70). Just needed to look a few lines up :)

If a resource is attached to the stack you can find it with:

```
CfnFunction cfnFunction = (CfnFunction) stack.getNode().tryFindChild("FunctionsLogicalId");
```